# Access to file to files a file in tomcat's conf folder

Tags: file, tomcat, configuration, classpath

I would like to know if it's possible to access a file putted on the conf folder of tomcat.
Typically i will put configuration for multiple webapp , outside of the wars, in this file.

I want to use the classpath to be independent from the file system.

I used the lib folder in the past. It work great.
But it's a bit of a none sense using the lib folder to put conf file.

Can someone help me on this one?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen lots of bad ways people do configuration in webapps that either makes it not really config (you have to do redeploy/release when you change config) or you have very little flexibility.

How I approach the problem is to use Spring for [property placeholder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) but often times you need to bootstrap Spring or whatever you MVC stack before it loads with a property that says where to load config. I use a listener for that:

```
package com.evocatus.util;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;


public class SimpleContextListenerConfig /*extend ResourceBundle */ implements ServletContextListener{

    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
        servletContext.setAttribute(getClass().getCanonicalName(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {

    }

    public static String getProperty(ServletContext sc, String propName, String defaultValue) {
        SimpleContextListenerConfig config = getConfig(sc);
        return config.getProperty(propName, defaultValue);
    }

    public static SimpleContextListenerConfig getConfig(ServletContext sc) {
        SimpleContextListenerConfig config = 
            (SimpleContextListenerConfig) sc.getAttribute(SimpleContextListenerConfig.class.getCanonicalName());
        return config;
    }

    public String getProperty(String propName, String defaultValue)
    {
        /*
         * TODO cache properties
         */
        String property = null; 

        if (property == null)
            property = servletContext.getInitParameter(propName);
        if (property == null)
            System.getProperty(propName, null);
        //TODO Get From resource bundle
        if (property == null)
            property = defaultValue;

        return property;
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/1083089

The properties will be pulled first from the servlet context, then system properties thus allowing you to override for certain webapps.
You can change the config for certian webapp either by changing web.xml (not recommended) or by [creating a context.xml](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html)

You can use the static methods to get the config:

```
public static SimpleContextListenerConfig getConfig(ServletContext sc);
```